# What would I have to add to this VBA Code to keep Undo Button working after it runs?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, undo, undo-redo

I was looking for VBA code so that any time I copy and paste text from anywhere into Excel, it will match the destination formatting. I found 2 different codes to do it:

```
Sub PasteWithDestinationFormatting()
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub PasteWithDestinationFormatting()
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

Both of them work but the problem is that they both disable the use of the "Undo" button, and the "Ctrl + Z" shortcut.  I'm trying to figure out why that is and what I can do to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: `Undo` functionality does not track VBA changes. - You would have to save what you want ahead of time and restore it manually if the user presses Ctrl-Z.

Comment: When you run some vba code that changes anything in a Workbook, the Undo stack is cleared.  So, if you want to undo something you did _before_ running the code, we'll, you can't.   That said,  there is `Application.OnUndo` that allows you to code an Undo function for your code.  It still won't undo anything done before your code ran.

Comment: Careful, using `xlPasteAll` will actually paste the source formatting. The reason it works in your case is probably because your are pasting text that has no formatting. To paste and preserve the destination formatting, use `xlPasteValues`.

Answer (score 0):

VBA destroys Excel's undo feature.
You could implement your own undo via VBA, though that would be quite complex.